# Appending to current line with log package

Tags: go, logging

I am writing a Go program and using the `log` package to write to a log file so that each new line will have a timestamp prepended to it. Sometimes I just want to append text to current line instead of starting a new line with the prepended timestamp.

I thought the `log.Print()` method would do this, as the docs say it is supposed to work the same way as fmt.Print(). Instead, I have found that each call to `Print()` generates a new line with a timestamp. I can't find another method in the package that does what I am looking for.

Is there a way to do this?

Example program:

```
logFile, err := os.Create("myLog.log")
defer logFile.Close()
logger := log.New(logFile, "", log.LstdFlags)

logger.Println("Starting first round")
for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.someapi.com/pgNum=" + i, nil)
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    logger.Print(".")
}

logger.Println("Starting second round")
for j := 1; j < 4; j++ {
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.someotherapi.com/pgNum=" + j, nil)
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    logger.Print(".")
}

logger.Println("Done")
```

Current output:

```
2019/09/18 13:27:49 Starting first round
2019/09/18 13:27:49 .
2019/09/18 13:27:50 .
2019/09/18 13:27:51 .
2019/09/18 13:27:52 Starting second round
2019/09/18 13:27:52 .
2019/09/18 13:27:53 .
2019/09/18 13:27:54 .
2019/09/18 13:27:55 Done
```

Desired output:

```
2019/09/18 13:27:49 Starting first round...
2019/09/18 13:27:52 Starting second round...
2019/09/18 13:27:55 Done
```

Comment: Maybe just change your logging pattern. Instead of appending log multiple messages with some progress information `First round [1/3]`,  `First round [3/3]`, `First round [2/3]`. It would be very easy to filter out.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, though this is just an abbreviated demo of what I'm trying to do. In the actual program, the number of iterations is not fixed (it calls the API to pull pages of data until it done, not for a fixed number), and in some cases the number of iterations for each API can number in the hundreds. I thought about logging a new line for each API call, but that would result in a log file that could be thousands of lines long, and I decided against that. I'm mostly interested in when an error occurs anyway, but the dots do let me know how many times an API was called.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be achived. Logging package always adds end of line character. See [log.go line 169](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go#L169).

The logs can be written by many routines, therefore you no have guarantee that you attach to the previously logged line.

Comment: Oh man, that is really inconvenient. Going to have to think about this some more.

Answer (score 1):

Grzegorz Żur is correct in his answer. Since the `log` package always appends a new line to the end of every string written to the log, there is no way to append more text to the end of that line when using that Writer, even if you bring in a different type of Writer to do the appends. I ended up having to roll my own.

Package:

```
package mylogger

import (
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "time"
)

var logWriter *bufio.Writer

func InitLogFile() (*os.File, error) {
    logFile, err := os.Create(logPath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    logWriter = bufio.NewWriter(logFile)

    return logFile, nil
}

func Print(msg string) {
    if logWriter != nil {
        logWriter.WriteString(msg)
        logWriter.Flush()
    }
}

func NewLine(msg string) {
    if logWriter != nil {
        logWriter.WriteString("\n" + time.Now().Format("2006/02/01 15:04:05") + " " + msg)
        logWriter.Flush()
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
logFile, err := mylogger.InitLogFile()
defer logFile.Close()

mylogger.NewLine("Starting first round")
for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.someapi.com/pgNum=" + i, nil)
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    mylogger.Print(".")
}

mylogger.NewLine("Starting second round")
for j := 1; j < 4; j++ {
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.someotherapi.com/pgNum=" + j, nil)
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    mylogger.Print(".")
}

mylogger.NewLine("Done")
```

This gets my desired result.

Important note: This only works because my program operates in a single thread and has a linear flow. If there were any concurrency where different subroutines could call into the logging function at any time, this would fall apart very quickly.

This is not my actual program, but an abbreviated gist of what it does. Error handling omitted for brevity. I'm not a Go expert, so I am open to comment.

Comment: If you use any concurrency, your logs may quickly become unreadable, with lines of interleaved messages from different goroutines.

Comment: @Adrian, you're right. Thankfully my program is only a single thread and the control flow is very linear. Otherwise I probably couldn't do this at all.